# Can't disable caps lock on Android

Tags: android

We have an app that is running on both iOS and Android. However, in the Android version, the keyboard is always set to caps-lock. In order to type in lower-case, the user will need to press shift for each letter.

We tried disabling textCapCharacters and using textCapSentences, but it did not fix the problem.

Sorry if I am not very clear. I am working for a publisher and the developer is in China. Let me know if you need clarification, and I will get it.

Comment: Imagine you're a medical doctor, and a friend of the patient writes you an e-mail complaining of a somewhat vague set of symptoms, but the patient does not make himself available for an examination. How would you proceed with your diagnosis? Ask your developer to send the relevant bits of code for us to see here, or better yet, ask him/her to post to Stack Overflow directly.

Comment: Is it a problem in a specific device or in all devices?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is something like below is set to that edit text.

```
android:capitalize="characters"
```